# Jquery autocomplete returns all the rows from the table, whereas PHP returns results as per the query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, web-applications, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Weird issue - Javascript has access to more data than what php is returning (or maybe that's how it appears).

Javascript: Following code returns all the records from the table regardless of what I'm searching (*term*) through the query.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        //autocomplete
        $(function() {

            $("#search").autocomplete({
                    source: function(request, response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "fetch_emojis.php",
                            method: 'post',
                            data: { term: request.term },
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function(data) {
                                response(data);
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    minLength: 1,
                    open: function(event, ui) {
                        $(".ui-autocomplete").css("z-index", 1000);
                    },
                })
                .autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
                    return $("<li><div><img src='" + item.img + "'><span>" + item.description + "</span></div></li>").appendTo(ul);
                };

        });
    });
```

PHP: Following code, if run separately returns rows as per the query (sample result set included)

```
<?php

if ( !isset($_REQUEST['term']) ) {
    exit;
}

$DB_host = "hostname"; 
$DB_login = "userid";
$DB_pass = "password";
$DB_select = "dbname";
$DB_port = "portnumber";

$mysqli = mysqli_connect($DB_host,$DB_login,$DB_pass,$DB_select,$DB_port);

$term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term'])); 
$term = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $term);

$a_json = array();
$a_json_row = array();

$a_json_invalid = array(array("id" => "#", "value" => $term, "label" => "Only letters and digits are permitted..."));
$json_invalid = json_encode($a_json_invalid);

if(preg_match("/[^\040\pL\pN_-]/u", $term)) {
  print $json_invalid;
  exit;
}


if ($data = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM emojis WHERE description LIKE '%$term%'")) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
        $id= htmlentities(stripslashes($row['id']));
        $description = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['description']));
        $source = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['source']));
        $a_json_row["id"] = $id;
        $a_json_row["description"] = $description;
        $a_json_row["img"] = $source;
        array_push($a_json, $a_json_row);
    }
}

echo json_encode($a_json);

?>
```

PHP Result for term = 'grin':

> [{"id":"1","description":"Grinning
>   Face","img":"https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/72/apple/155/grinning-face_1f600.png"},{"id":"5","description":"Grinning
>   Face With Big
>   Eyes","img":"https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/72/apple/155/smiling-face-with-open-mouth_1f603.png"},{"id":"6","description":"Grinning
>   Face With Smiling
>   Eyes","img":"https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/72/apple/155/smiling-face-with-open-mouth-and-smiling-eyes_1f604.png"},{"id":"7","description":"Grinning
>   Face With
>   Sweat","img":"https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/72/apple/155/smiling-face-with-open-mouth-and-cold-sweat_1f605.png"},{"id":"8","description":"Grinning
>   Squinting
>   Face","img":"https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/72/apple/155/smiling-face-with-open-mouth-and-tightly-closed-eyes_1f606.png"},{"id":"102","description":"Grinning
>   Cat
>   Face","img":"https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/72/apple/155/smiling-cat-face-with-open-mouth_1f63a.png"},{"id":"103","description":"Grinning
>   Cat Face With Smiling
>   Eyes","img":"https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/72/apple/155/grinning-cat-face-with-smiling-eyes_1f638.png"}]

Any thoughts around what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: In your php code `$term` is getting from `$_GET`, but in your ajax request you put your data in `$_POST` and your filter do not apply, thats why i think you get all data with ajax

Comment: Actually i think your code should throw an error on this line `$term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term'])); ` with ajax request.

Comment: @VolodymyrMokhonko  I wasn't aware that the frontend declaration of the method could override the way server-side scripts access data!  That helped. Thank you so much.

Comment: Ironically, I haven't encountered any errors. Even at $term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));

Comment: This is pretty weird because with ajax request in your case `$_GET` shouldn't contain `term` key at all. Try to dump your globals to clarify script behavior.

Comment: It still works. Why do you say, "$_GET shouldn't contain term key at all"?

Comment: Because according to your JS code you didn't set any params with `term` key to GET, do you tried to dump `$_GET` in your php code?

Comment: I made changes as per your first comment and it started working. I haven't dumped, but I did try with different values for the term - It works.